# Angular 8 selected option number and alphabet

Tags: angular

I have a problem with the option selected

when the name_step = "ABCD" is selected but

when the name_step = "1" is not selected.

why this can happen, even though I set both as strings

this my code :

```
<option *ngFor="let step of listStep | keyvalue" value={{step.value.id}}  selected="{{step.value.name === name_step ? 'selected' : '' }}">
          {{ step.value.name | titlecase }}</option>
```

and i have 3 option

```
option 1 [id = 1, name = "1"],
option 2 [id = 2, name = "2"],
option 3 [id = 3, name = "ABCD"]
```

and this code name_step :

```
this.name_step = params['params']['name_step'];
```

Comment: can you try creating a demo on https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: sorry it not clear what you trying ask here

Comment: You want to keep 1 as the selected option in the dropdown on page load. Is that it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yhz7kj-tssic4)

***I am not sure I am getting your question right but might you asking something like this***

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Cars</mat-label>
  <select matNativeControl required>
   <option *ngFor="let step of listStep " value={{step.id}}  selected="{{step.name == name_step ? 'selected' : '' }}">
          {{ step.name | titlecase }}</option>
  </select>
</mat-form-field>
```

> Ts file code

```
name_step='ABCD';

  listStep: any[] = [
    { id: 1, name: "1" },
    { id: 2, name: "2" },
    { id: 3, name: "ABCD" }
  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep "1" selected on page load, you can do this:

**Component:**

```
listStep = [
    {id : 1, name : "1"},
    {id : 2, name : "2"},
    {id : 3, name : "ABCD"}
]

selectedStep = this.listStep.find(x=>x.id == 1); //Keep 1 selected.

onChange(){
    console.log(this.selectedStep);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedStep" (change)="onChange()">
    <option *ngFor="let step of listStep" [ngValue]="step">{{step.name}}</option>
</select>
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ms8zcb)